# Error while trying to inject with services.AddScoped

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I am building a WarehouseApi, but when I try to inject my service it gives me an error(CS0119)

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
            services.AddScoped(IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository); //CS0119
            return services;
        }
```

Error descriptions: EmployeeRepository' is a type, which is not valid in the given context and
IEmployeeRepository' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Here are IEmployeeRepository and EmployeeRepository:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
    {
        Employee GetFirstOrDefaultByFirstName(string firstNameToFind);
        Employee GetFirstOrDefaultByLastName(string lastNameToFind);
        Employee GetFirstOrDefaultbByAge(int ageToFind);
        Employee GetByEmail(string emailToFind);
        Employee GetByAddress(string addressToFind);
        Employee GetByPhoneNumber(string phoneNumberToFind);
    }

public class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
    {
        public EmployeeRepository(WareHouseDBContext empContext) : base(empContext) { }

        public Employee GetByAddress(string addressToFind)
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address == addressToFind);
        }

        public Employee GetByEmail(string emailToFind)
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == emailToFind);
        }

        public Employee GetByPhoneNumber(string phoneNumberToFind)
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumberToFind);
        }

        public Employee GetFirstOrDefaultbByAge(int ageToFind)
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Age == ageToFind);
        }

        public Employee GetFirstOrDefaultByFirstName(string firstNameToFind)
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstName == firstNameToFind);
        }

        public Employee GetFirstOrDefaultByLastName(string lastNameToFind)
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName == lastNameToFind);
        }
    }
```

I'm new to APIs, Dependency Injection, etc, so this might be an easy fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method that accepts type arguments to resolve the compiler warning:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
```

However if you're not using .NET 5.0 or later, then open generics (`IFoo<>`) is not supported by the built-in DI container.

In that case you'll need to register it like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Employee>, EmployeeRepository>();
```

Support for open generics is available from .NET 5.0 ([PR](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/39540)). There's some more information about it [here](https://jimmybogard.com/constrained-open-generics-support-merged-in-net-core-di-container/).

Comment: I  tried it, it gives me no errors but it doesn't work in a controller

Comment: When I try your method and make an API call it gives me the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WareHouseApp.Repository.EmployeeRepositories.EmployeeRepository' while attempting to activate 'WareHouseApp.API.Controllers.EmployeeController'.`

Comment: Have you registered `WareHouseDBContext` with DI?

Comment: Yes with this `services.AddDbContext<WareHouseDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(datasource));`

Comment: Try looking deeper into the exception and/or logs. The DI system will usually tell you why it can't activate a specific type.

Comment: I updated it to .NET 5.0 and now it gives me another error `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

WareHouseApp.API.Controllers.EmployeeController.GetByAddress (WareHouseApp.API)
WareHouseApp.API.Controllers.EmployeeController.GetById (WareHouseApp.API)`

Comment: Well that's a totally different problem related to endpoint routing, not DI. I suggest you open a new question and provide your controller code if you need further help.

Comment: Back to the System.InvalidOperationException above, I'm guessing that your constructor for EmployeeController has (EmployeeRepository repo).  That needs to be (IEmployeeRepository repo).  Declare the interface in the constructor, not the concrete.

Comment: @MartinCostello No need, I had a mistake in my routes, I just needed to add route constraints.